# My salary is always late and some deductions are not done

Tags: salary

I work in a law house as an advocate. I have been there for 4 months but I never receive my salary on time. I get my salary every month after the 15th. Whenever I ask about it, he says "let the money come from the clients." Also, there are more than 25 employees, but my boss does not deduct my pf. I want to make a complaint to prevent this wrong practice.

How can I ensure I am paid on time and my pf is deducted?

Comment: please include the country.

Comment: You need to talk a lawyer, not the Internet.... oh, wait a minute. You *are* a lawyer, so you hopefully know some people who can give you advice here.

Comment: @PhilipKendall she's an advocate, not a lawyer. Not everyone that works at a law firm is an actual lawyer...

Comment: What is pf? As in "my boss does not deduct my pf"?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to be sure, but you seem to have two issues:

- sometimes you are paid up to two weeks late, and your employer says it's because they are waiting on money from customers. This is called a "cash flow" problem - the company doesn't have reserves, so if clients pay late, staff and vendors get paid late. It should not happen for 4 solid months in a company with 25 employees. Either the company is poorly run or they are deceiving you. Neither is good.
- you are not having something (pf? no idea what that is) deducted from your pay that should be. This would be distressing in any employer, but a law firm certainly should know the law and comply with the law.

You don't say where you live, but many countries have a "citizens advice" service which is free to all and deals with general issues like employment, landlord/tenant, and such. If you have one, go see them. If you don't, then perhaps you have a Ministry or Department of Labor. Call them (not from a work phone) and ask for advice.

I would encourage you to start looking for another job. Sooner or later the only solution to persistent cashflow problems is to make the company smaller. And companies that are lying to their staff and not complying with workplace law also tend to close their doors. So having somewhere to go is your best strategy, in addition to whatever actions you want to take to get this employer to pay you on time and deduct the right things.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of where you're working, your employer should be very tight and transparent about your pay with you. The fact that he said "let the money come from the clients" is a HUGE red flag and I would run.